# Checking if value exists in name attribute

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

```xml
<root>
  <data name="ID1"></data>
  <data name="ID2"></data>
</root>
```

```cs
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(xmlFile);

bool exists = (from elem in xmlDoc.Descendants("root")
               where elem.Element("data").Attribute("name").Value == "ID1"
               select elem).Any();
```

It doesn't see that ID1 already exists.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the type for `XMLDoc`?  Is it an `XDocument` or is it an `XElement`?  Is that your actual XML?  It isn't valid XML (the `data` nodes are not closed).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on what you've shown, first I have to point out that the XML snippet is not valid XML.  The `data` nodes are not closed.

Assuming this is a valid XML document, it would ultimately depend on what the type is for your variable `XMLDoc`.

If it was an `XDocument`, then that code snippet should work and the value of `exists` would be `true`.  The document contains a descendant called `root` and it could go about its business.

If it was an `XElement` on the other hand, then that code snippet should fail and the value of `exists` would be `false`.  The `XMLDoc` variable would be referring to the `root` element already and there clearly isn't any descendants called `root`.

You should rewrite your query however, maybe something more like this:

```
// please follow .NET naming conventions and use lowercase for local variables
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(xmlFile);

// iterate over the `data` elements, not the `root` elements
bool exists = (from data in xmlDoc.Element("root").Elements("data")
               where (string)data.Attribute("name") == "ID1"
               select data).Any();
// using the cast is a personal style choice
// using `XAttribute.Value` is fine too in this case
```

Comment: so yours worked. why doesn't mine work? btw, thanks for the insight!

Comment: I think what's killing your code is that you are iterating over the `root` elements and not the `data` elements which is why I suggested the rewrite.  Your code will only examine the first `data` element and ignore the rest.  Your XML might have a different ordering which could explain why it's failing.